# ggplot2 error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (24)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot in ggplot showing the mean home range size of an animal according to different sexes, treatments, time periods and seasons. I get an error in R saying

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (24): x, y, colour, shape"

I have read similar posts about this error but I haven't been able to figure it out yet. There are no NA's in these columns and my numerical variables are being treated as such. Not sure if the error has to do with a need to sub set the data but I don't understand how I should do that. My code runs fine up until the ggplot part and it is the following:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")

lion_HR_size <- read.csv(file = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23723553/lion_sample_data.csv",
           header= TRUE, row.names=1)

# Mean of home range size by season, treatment, sex and time
Mean_HR <- lion_HR_size %>%
group_by(season, treatment, sex, time) %>%
summarize(
mean_HR = mean(Area_HR_km),
se_HR = sd(Area_HR_km)/sqrt(n()),
lwrHR = mean_HR - se_HR,
uprHR = mean_HR + se_HR)

limitsHR <- aes(ymin = lwrHR, ymax= uprHR)

ggplot(Mean_HR, 
aes(x=season, 
y= Mean_HR, 
colour=season, 
shape= season)) + 
geom_point( size = 6, alpha = 0.5)+
facet_grid(sex ~ treatment+time)+
geom_errorbar(limitsHR, width = 0.1, col = 'red', alpha = 0.8)+
theme_bw()
```

As requested, the dput(Mean_HR) output is the following:

> dput(Mean_HR)
>   structure(list(season = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>   3L), .Label = c("Early_dry", "Late_dry", "Wet"), class = "factor"), 
>       treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
>       ), .Label = c("C", "E"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(1L, 
>       1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
>       1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
>       time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
>       1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
>       "B"), class = "factor"), mean_HR = c(141.594090181, 138.327188493, 
>       509.287443507692, 345.296845642381, 157.634028930833, 184.202160663125, 
>       252.464096340667, 255.078012825, 59.8485325981818, 143.158189516522, 
>       439.990400912593, 175.410885601333, 221.338774452381, 100.942251723636, 
>       127.961533612727, 167.199563142143, 120.60363022375, 142.351764574211, 
>       249.03854219, 330.018734301176, 123.992902995714, 219.886321226667, 
>       307.869373359167, 296.019550844286), se_HR = c(18.6245437612391, 
>       29.2548378154774, 127.987824704623, 78.9236194797204, 20.8897993194466, 
>       43.1314245224751, 57.6327505533691, 32.1129054260719, 9.383853530199, 
>       38.7678333459788, 130.348285186224, 31.707304307485, 29.1561478797825, 
>       15.4038723326613, 18.1932127432015, 37.791782522185, 32.7089231722616, 
>       33.2629181623941, 46.1500408067739, 88.8736578370159, 15.8046627788777, 
>       36.9665360444972, 70.1560303348504, 87.1340476758794), lwrHR = c(122.969546419761, 
>       109.072350677523, 381.29961880307, 266.373226162661, 136.744229611387, 
>       141.07073614065, 194.831345787298, 222.965107398928, 50.4646790679828, 
>       104.390356170543, 309.642115726369, 143.703581293848, 192.182626572598, 
>       85.5383793909751, 109.768320869526, 129.407780619958, 87.8947070514884, 
>       109.088846411816, 202.888501383226, 241.145076464161, 108.188240216837, 
>       182.91978518217, 237.713343024316, 208.885503168406), uprHR = c(160.218633942239, 
>       167.582026308477, 637.275268212315, 424.220465122101, 178.52382825028, 
>       227.3335851856, 310.096846894036, 287.190918251072, 69.2323861283808, 
>       181.9260228625, 570.338686098816, 207.118189908818, 250.494922332163, 
>       116.346124056298, 146.154746355929, 204.991345664328, 153.312553396012, 
>       175.614682736605, 295.188582996774, 418.892392138192, 139.797565774592, 
>       256.852857271164, 378.025403694017, 383.153598520165)), class = c("grouped_df", 
>   "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), vars = list(
>       season, treatment, sex), drop = TRUE, .Names = c("season", 
>   "treatment", "sex", "time", "mean_HR", "se_HR", "lwrHR", "uprHR"
>   ))

Could someone help me understand this error and how to fix it in my code? Many thanks!

Comment: In your example you name your dataset `size` but then you summarize one called `lion_HR_size`.  Can you just copy and paste the result of `dput(Mean_HR)` into your question?

Comment: dropbox link is dead anyway.

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed the name of the file and the dropbox link is working again. I also included the dput(Mean_HR) in my question aosmith. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Don't know why, but for me I can't read your dput() output, it gives an error.

Comment: You have a typo - you  named your dataset `Mean_HR` and your column `mean_HR` but then you used `y = Mean_HR` in your plot code.  It is expecting a variable for `y`, not a dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure myself why/how the `limitsHR <- ...` statement works. I would have expected it to stop on not being able to find the `lwrHR` and `uprHR` objects in the workspace.

Anyhow, ggplot has a nice function mean_se() that will help you tremendously.

```
ggplot(data = lion_HR_size, mapping = aes(x = season, y = Area_HR_km, 
                                          colour=season, shape= season)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se) +
  facet_grid(sex ~ treatment+time)+
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you, that mean_se() does help a lot!